# How do you move between an observer's frame orbiting a Kerr B-H and the B-H's frame? In context of photon emission from accretion disk.

Tags: differential-geometry, physics, general-relativity

I'm struggling with the concept of moving to and from reference frames in GR. I'm doing a problem in Spacetime and Geometry by S. Carroll (Chapter 6, Question 6 - the text for the question is very long) and it's the idea of iron in an accretion disk on geodesics emitting photons of known frequency $$\nu_{0}$$ and then, depending on where the photon is emitted and the direction of rotation of the accretion disk compared to the Kerr B-H, what is the frequency of the photon measured by an observer very far away. One method I tried was using, from earlier in the book, $$\omega = -g_{\mu \nu}U^{\mu}\frac{dx^{\nu}}{d\lambda}$$ then if you assume the observer is stationary, and in the equatorial plane (as given in the question) you get that $$\omega = (1 - \frac{2GM}{r})^{\frac{-1}{2}}E$$ from the Killing vector and the normalisation of U in the Kerr metric. Then I think that the energy will be conserved along the Killing vector so just take $$E = \nu_{0}$$ if hbar = 1. So you end up with the formula $$\frac{\omega}{\nu_{0}} = (1 - \frac{GM}{r})^{\frac{-1}{2}}$$ which is just the Schwarzchild redshift formula right?

So clearly this doesn't depend on anything to do with the accretion disk, or even the 'angular momentum' of the Kerr B-H, and I definitely feel like I'm doing something wrong. Furthermore, I have rearranged the Killing vectors for L and E then used them, and the fact the photon is on a null path in the equatorial plane, to get the full form for the dx/d(lambda) in terms of conserved quantities. I want to try doing the idea of moving between frames of a particle in the accretion disk but I'm really struggling with deriving the transformation between the particle's rest frame and then Black-Hole's frame. I'm thinking along the lines of the preservation of the line element and saying that, in a very small vicinity around the particle, spacetime looks like Minkowski spacetime so, using again that we're in the equatorial plane, $$ds^2 = -dt'^2 + dr'^2 + r^2d{\phi'}^2 = -(1 - \frac{2GM}{r})dt^2 + \frac{2GMa}{r}(dtd{\phi} + d{\phi}dt) + \frac{r^2}{\Delta}dr^2 + \frac{\Sigma^2}{r^2}d{\phi}^2$$ where $$\Sigma^2 = [(r^2 + a^2)^2 - a^2{\Delta} ] || \Delta = r^2 - 2GMr + a^2$$ then if you leave all the other components constant, you get the effects of, for example, $$\frac{dr'}{dr} = \frac{r}{\sqrt{\Delta}} $$ I'm really not sure if this is correct. I've also had some ideas like $$U^{\mu'} = \frac{\partial{x^{\mu'}}}{\partial{x^{\mu}}}U^{\mu}$$ where the particle frame is un-primed and the Black-Hole frame is primed, but still I'm struggling to find (convincingly) the partial derivatives.

Please can someone give me a push in the right direction? I'm self studying (lockdown and all that) and I feel I'm missing some little conceptual, well basic, ideas like this. I don't know if this is against Stack Exchange policy, but please can you not give a full answer to Carroll's question, I would still like to try and fill in the gaps!

Comment: It seems that one would also need to take into account the initial direction of the photon relative to the velocity of the accretion disk. It may be the case that this direction is determined by the direction of the escaping photon, but it could also be the case that multiple null geodesics could have the same asymptotic trajectories, and different redshifts.

Comment: Kajelad - Thanks for the reply. You're certainly right, in my head you get a Doppler-type shift depending on the direction of the accretion disk. I think there's a formula for it but I'm pretty uneasy about just using a formula, I want to do it from changing frames from a particle in the accretion disk to the B-H ecc. That's what I'm struggling with, the change of frames/

Comment: The "change of frames" would be given by $E=-u^\alpha p_\alpha$ where $E$ is the energy of the photon in the source frame, $u$ is the velocity of the disk at the emission, and $p_\alpha$ is the initial momentum of the photon (this is essentially SR, since everything happens locally and instantaneously). The issue is that relating this to an energy of the escaped photon seems to require you know the photon's path. You can certainly establish upper/lower bounds, though.

Comment: But you can figure out the trajectory (or the momentum even) of the photon totally, no? Because $$\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$$ you can use the Killing vectors to solve for all the components, except the $$\frac{d\theta}{d\lambda}$$ as this is always zero, by using the line element? Either way, I think you're right with that formula, I wasn't using it correctly. I'm going to try to that and see what pops out, thank you

Comment: It's true that $\theta(\lambda)=\pi/2$, but it remains to solve for the other three coordinates. This amounts to solving the (null) geodesic equation in $2+1$ dimensions to relate the (asymptotic) final velocity to the initial position/velocity.

Comment: Can it not be done by using the Killing vectors though? If $E = -K_{\mu}\frac{dx^{\mu}}{d\lambda} $ and $ L = R_{\mu}\frac{dx^{\mu}}{d\lambda}$ then you have a system that you can rewrite in matrix form, then invert for $ \frac{dt}{d\lambda} $ and $ \frac{d\phi}{d\lambda}$ ? Then use the fact that the photon's momentum is null to solve for $ \frac{dr}{d\lambda}$ , as was a previous problem in the chapter? Could these not then be solved to get the trajectory, but do I actually need the trajectory?

Comment: You can absolutely use Killing vectors to solve for the remaining quantities. Note that the constant of motion $E$ in your previous comment is not the same as the energy of the photon in the source's frame. If you just want to find the observed frequency of the photon given the initial condition, this is the only constant you need.